# How is a ring formed when a carbon atom in an aliphatic chain attached to benzene ring has a positive charge?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

This is my approach towards this problem. First off, a positive charge would appear in the C atom at the end of the chain, and then that carbocation would rearrange into a tertiary carbocation.

But I am not being able to figure out what will be the next step. Can the carbocation extract a hydrogen from the benzene ring to form another five-membered chain as the formation of a five-membered rings is very feasible?

[image: Ring formation]

Comment: Yes, Definitely. The carbocation won't extract proton from Benzene ring, the $\pi$-electron cloud of benzene ring will attack to the carbocation to form the fused five-membered ring and a proton will be lost to rearomatise the system.

Comment: You need to review cation rearrangements.

Comment: @SoumikDas so should the benzene ring attack from the carbon opposite to the carbon bearing the -och3 group , as then the carbanion formed would be more stable?

Comment: Yes there will be electrophilic addition at the para position to form a 5-membered ring.

Comment: @PrathamYadav Yes, I think so, as attack from the ortho position of $\ce{-OCH3}$will make lot of steric crowding, attack from para position of $\ce{-OCH3}$ should be more favoured..

Comment: You should be familiar with the Friedel-Crafts (FC) alkylation reaction - this is just an example where the nucleophile (aromatic ring) and electrophile (alkyl halide) are connected by a piece of string (the alkyl chain). For me there are a couple of possible products: the FC reaction could occur directly on the primary carbocation, forming a 6-membered ring, or there could be an initial 1,2-hydride shift to generate the more stable tertiary carbocation, where the subsequent Friedel-Crafts would give a 5-ring. Which occurs depends on the relative rates of intramolecular FC vs hydride shift.